# Find matching array content and length on a single inner property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to get a query to work correctly, but for the life of me I'm getting stuck.

```
  'chat.newDirect': function(otherUser) {
      CEChats.collection.find({
            $and: [
                { 
                    members:{
                    $elemMatch: {memberId: this.userId}
                }
            },
                { 
                    members:{
                    // $elemMatch: {memberId: otherUser._id}
                        $all: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                memberId: otherUser.$._id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }).fetch();
```

Originally otherUser was a single object, but now its been changed to be an array of objects.

What I'm trying to do is find the documents that have all of the ID's in the `otherUser` array.

`otherUser._id` needs to match one of the elements in `members.memberId` array.

I also want it to only return documents that have the exact member list, so not extra's on top of these, so I was going to add a length check also to do this.

~edit for clarifications
`otherUser` is the object array passed into the function

```
[
    {_id: 1, fu:'fuu', bar:'baar'},
    {_id: 2, fu:'fuu', bar:'baar'},
    {_id: 3, fu:'fuu', bar:'baar'}
]
```

`members` is the object array in the document I'm comparing against.

```
[
{members: [
    {_id: 1, baz:'fuu'},
    {_id: 2, baz:'fuu'},
    {_id: 3, baz:'fuu'},
    {_id: 4, baz:'fuu'},
    {_id: 5, baz:'fuu'}
]},
{members: [
    {_id: 1, baz:'fuu'},
    {_id: 2, baz:'fuu'},
    {_id: 3, baz:'fuu'}
]},
{members: [
    {_id: 1, baz:'fuu'}
]}
]
```

After running the query, only the second object should be returned as it's the only one that contains all the member ID's in the objects in the member array

Comment: Are you saying that there are two arrays in the document and you want to find if they have overlapping elements? Not really that clear what you are saying. Can you show an example of data and what you want to achieve please?

Comment: @NeilLunn ive added an example that i hope clarifies it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your source and then pass the query using both [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/):

```
var otherIds = [
  {_id: 1, fu:'fuu', bar:'baar'},
  {_id: 2, fu:'fuu', bar:'baar'},
  {_id: 3, fu:'fuu', bar:'baar'}
];

var ids = otherIds.map( oth => oth._id );

CEChats.collection.find({ 
    "members._id": { "$all": ids },
    "members": { "$size": ids.length } 
}).fetch()
```

Which returns the second result:

```
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "baz" : "fuu"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "baz" : "fuu"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "baz" : "fuu"
            }
    ]
```

So you first use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) to just extract the `_id` values. Then you can pass in with [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) with `"members._id"` to just compare on the `_id` value of that array's content. The other constraint is the exact [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) which you can get from the comparison array `.length` property.

Comment: I had just started to do the transformations after I typed out the clarification part.

Thanks for your help  :D